# Present italics font in jqgrid column

Tags: fonts, jqgrid, italics

I would like to ask you, if its possible to present the contents of a specific column in a jqGrid table with italics font. I searched for it but couldn't find anything. So is there any way to achieve something like this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need declare CSS rule which uses some class, for example `"myclass"`:

```css
.myclass { font-style: italic; }
```

Then you need to add `classes: "myclass"` property to the column definition of the specific column where you need to have italic text. It's all.